# 'could not find' function error

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, plugins, jquery-plugins

I have a html page which adds a reference to jquery library.  I then have dialog window which loads the jquery library again.

At this point, I have a jquery plugin #1 which calls another jquery plugin #2 and i get error like jquery pluging 2 cannot be found.

If i remove a reference to the first jquery library things seem to work.  Why would adding a 2nd reference to jquery (for the dialog) cause this issue?  How can i resolve?

My plugin (in external file is defined like)

```
(function ($) {

    $.fn.finder = function (optionsIn) {
               //do stuff   
               ..
              //2nd call to plugin this is where i get the error
              $(this).watermark('watermark');

    };
})(jQuery);
```

The plugin works fine on a simple html page however if i use the plugin on a dialog it has issues with the multiple references to the jquery library.

Ideas?

I am using the watermark plugin https://github.com/fabrikagency/fa-watermark with typical usage like `$('input').watermark('Enter your name.','my-custom-class');`

Comment: Show the `watermark` definition. Also, inside a $.fn.func_name` function, `this` is a jQuery object. So, do not wrap it in another jQuery object.

Comment: Yes, using $(this) seems to be fine when not using the plugin in a dialog (remember with dialog implementation, the main references the jquery library and the dialog also references it)..it works ok if i remove one of the references to jquery 

why would that be?

Comment: You have to include the watermark plugin before including your own external script file containing `finder`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the input.  It made me look very carefully of the order of items getting loaded.  It appears the issue was that my plugin was getting loaded before jquery.  This also answers why if i put $('inputelement').pluginOne('') within a $(document).ready(function () {
 }); then it worked ok.  This worked cause it didn't try to attach the plugin until after everything was loaded.